# How many different ways to sit persons on each longer side of rectangular table, with a moderator at the head?

Tags: combinatorics

We have:

-> rectangular table with moderator fix at one side;

-> 2 persons of each one of 4 nationalities (8);

-> there are 4 seats on opposite 2 sides of the table

Restriction: people of the same nationality must sit together.

Attempt: since there is a moderator, every configuration is different. Considering only the disposition of the four pairs around the table, we have 4! possibilities. Now we need to take into account the permutations inside each group: 2. This points to a total of 4!x2x2x2x2.

Sadly I was told this is wrong. What do you think is the right answer and why?

Comment: Without more information, your answer seems correct. But, there are questions. For example: what constitutes a configuration? If you were to consider all of the seats starting with the person to the moderator's left and going around the table until you reach the moderator's right, is that the same as if the exact same people were seated in reverse order? Additionally, what does it mean that two people of the same nationality must sit together? Does that mean on the same side of the table, or directly adjacent to each other?

Comment: And do the people at the ends count as sitting next to each other? I realize the moderator is between two of them, but if the moderator shares a nationality with the two people on either side, it might be a valid configuration.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe: In my opinion, there is no chance for simmetric seating around the table, taking in account the whole of the seats, because of the moderator; he's like a broken chair. Regarding the 2nd issue, I consider sitting together when they are shoulder on shoulder; this forces 2 pairs on each side for a valid configuration. The moderator's nationality is irrelevant, he is there only to avoid interpreting this as a round table problem, as far as I see. The book states 48 as the right answer. Can't accept it.

Comment: Let's consider this another way. There's eight people who can be seated to the left of the moderator. There's one person who cam sit to that person's left. There's six people who can sit to that person's left, and one person at the end of the table. There's four people left who can sit to the right of the moderator and one to that person's right. Either of the remaining two people can sit in the next available seat and that leaves only one person for the last seat. That's $8!!=8\cdot 6\cdot 4\cdot 2=384=4!(2)^4$. Unless there are symmetries, that's the answer.